# Visual Studio can run any individual microservice but fails with multiple startup projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, microservices

I have a solution of .NET 5 microservices.  If I select any microservice as the startup project it runs fine, opening Swagger UI in my default browser.  However, I need to run two microservices simultaneously (one calls the other).

I configured Multiple startup projects and set the two microservices to start.  But when I click the Start button to run the projects I get the following error:

[image: Error dialog when attempt to run two startup projects]

What do I need to do to fix the issue and allow the two microservices to run simultaneously?  As far as I can see there is no additional startup configuration available when selecting multiple startup projects.

I'm not sure if the following is relevant to this issue or not:

I notice that when configured to only run one project the Visual Studio Start button shows "IIS Express" and has a dropdown for further configuration:

[image: Startup dropdown with a single startup project selected]

While with multiple startup projects selected the Start button shows "Start" and doesn't have similar configuration items in the dropdown list:

[image: Startup dropdown with multiple startup projects selected]

Comment: Hi @Simon Elms, it is not related with microservices or the picture you shared. You can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server?view=vs-2022) to check if any problems.

Comment: Thanks @Rena.  I didn't find the detailed error message I was seeing in the link you provided.  However, playing around with Visual Studio eventually fixed the problem.  Not sure exactly what I did that fixed the issue but I haven't experienced it in the last day or so.